# Hidden syntax errors in MYSQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, cursor, mysql-workbench

I'm new to MYSQL and this is my first time creating a procedure so bear with me. I'm trying to loop through information_scheme.tables and populate a new table with info taken from some of the tables found there. I cannot save the procedure in workbench because of 'syntax errors'. I cannot figure out what those errors are however.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `populate` ()
BEGIN
DECLARE thisDay varchar(100);
DECLARE i int;
DECLARE n int;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM (information_schema.tables);
SET i=0;
SELECT COUNT(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables INTO n;
OPEN cur;
    getDay: LOOP
     IF cur LIKE 'transactions_20%' THEN 
     FETCH cur INTO thisDay;
     
     INSERT INTO days_totals
     (date,num_of_ppl,punches,admission_total,pass_total,misc_total,food_total,drink_total,grand_total)
     VALUES(
     (SELECT SUBSTRING(thisDay,14,23)),
     (SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM thisDay WHERE name = 'adult admission' OR name = 'punch a pass' OR name = 'child admission'),
     (SELECT COUNT(amount) FROM thisDay WHERE name = 'punch a pass'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM thisDay WHERE name = 'adult admission' OR name = 'child admission'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM thisDay WHERE name = 'ten visit pass'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM thisDay WHERE type = 'misc' AND name != 'adult admission' AND name != 'child admission' AND name != 'ten visit pass'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM thisDay WHERE type = 'food'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM thisDay WHERE type = 'drink'),
     (SELECT SUM(total) FROM thisDay WHERE type = 'misc' OR type = 'food' OR type = 'drink')
     );
     SET i = i + 1;
     ELSE IF
        i < n AND cur NOT LIKE 'transactions_20%' THEN SET i = i + 1;
     ELSE
     LEAVE getDay;
     
     END IF;
     END LOOP getDay;
     CLOSE cur;
END
```

Comment: You need to set `DELIMITER` before the CREATE PROCEDURE. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html for explanation.

Comment: @BillKarwin they say they are using workbench, so delimiter shouldn't be needed?  (though usually problems using workbench are best solved by not using workbench :) )

Comment: @ysth I tested it in Workbench. There's a syntax error on the first line with `;`, and the error goes away after using `DELIMITER`. I agree about Workbench, I don't use it.

Comment: *`DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM (information_schema.tables);`* You add brackets - what do you want to do with them? The table mentioned in the brackets cannot be converted to scalar value. *`IF cur LIKE 'transactions_20%' THEN`* In this code `cur` is opened cursor - how do you want to apply LIKE to it? *`SELECT .. FROM thisDay WHERE`* In this code - do you want the variable name `thisDay` to be expanded with its value? this won't be performed. PS. These are the grossest errors..

Comment: @Akina I added brackets in the hopes of eliminating the syntax error. If I'm being honest, I have no clue what I'm doing. I found a couple of examples of cursors online and tried to write mine based on their logic and syntax, but I don't fully understand the logic yet. I'm only used to JS and C# so I think in this case I was treating cur as 'i' would be treated in a for loop. What would I replace 'cur' with in my LIKE statement? I assume thisDay is storing values taken from information_schema.tables so what I was trying to do was take those and plug them into the INSERT statements

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems with your procedure code.

- You need to set the DELIMITER, even when using MySQL Workbench. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html
- You can't use a variable in place of the table name. To make the table name dynamic, you must format the table name into an SQL query string, and then use PREPARE. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html
- You are comparing the cursor to a string, but you should compare the value fetched by the cursor.
- You don't need a condition anyway, because you should just use a WHERE clause in your query against information_schema.tables.
- Your cursor has no way of continuing. You don't declare a continue handler, and you just LEAVE the loop during the first iteration. Read examples more carefully: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html
- Your `i` and `n` variables appear to have no purpose. You count up, but the value you count is not used.

I made the following version and tested it on MySQL 8.0. I used MySQL Workbench to create the procedure.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test.`populate`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE thisDay varchar(100);
  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name LIKE 'transactions_20%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur;

  getDay: LOOP
     FETCH cur INTO thisDay;
     IF done THEN
       LEAVE getDay;
     END IF;
     
     SET @sql = CONCAT(
       'SELECT 
         COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN (''adult admission'', ''punch a pass'', ''child admission'') THEN amount END),
         COUNT(CASE WHEN name IN (''punch a pass'') THEN amount END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN name IN (''adult admission'', ''child admission'') THEN total END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN name IN (''ten visit pass'') THEN total END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN name IN (''ten visit pass'') THEN total END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN type = ''misc'' AND name NOT IN (''adult admission'', ''child admission'', ''ten visit pass'') THEN total END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN type = ''food'' THEN total END),
         SUM(CASE WHEN type IN (''misc'', ''food'', ''drink'') THEN total END)
       FROM `', thisDay, '`
       INTO @v_num_of_ppl, @v_punches, @v_admission_total, @v_pass_total, @v_misc_total, @v_food_total, @v_drink_total, @v_grand_total'
     );
     
     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
     
     INSERT INTO days_totals
     SET date = SUBSTRING(thisDay, 14, 23),
         num_of_ppl=COALESCE(@v_num_of_ppl, 0),
         punches=COALESCE(@v_punches, 0),
         admission_total=COALESCE(@v_admission_total, 0),
         pass_total=COALESCE(@v_pass_total, 0),
         misc_total=COALESCE(@v_misc_total, 0),
         food_total=COALESCE(@v_food_total, 0),
         drink_total=COALESCE(@v_drink_total, 0),
         grand_total=COALESCE(@v_grand_total, 0);

   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cur;
END
```

By using `CASE` expressions inside the aggregation, this collects all the subtotals in one pass of reading the transactions table.

---

Frankly, I would not use a stored procedure at all. This task would be easier in virtually any other application programming language. There is no advantage to using a stored procedure in this case, and it's a language you are not accustomed to.

Comment: I had the same thought - how it would be so much easier to just do this in C#, but I was being stubborn haha. Thank you for the detailed notes and for the rewrite. I'll look over everything carefully and try to better understand what's going on here.

Comment: Stored procedures are de rigueur in some other brands of SQL database like Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server or DB2. But specifically MySQL's implementation of stored routines is so inefficient and difficult to use, that I hardly ever recommend using them. I think they did a proof of concept implementation of stored routines in 2005 mostly as a checkbox feature, and they hardly touched them since then.